# ExtJS 4 - Combobox visually select the previous selection and the current

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a combobox:

```
{
                xtype: 'combo',
                id: 'tfecomboEstados',
                fieldLabel :'Estado',
                forceSelection:true,
                queryMode: 'local',
                editable: false,
                displayField: 'label',
                valueField: 'value',
                store: 'combostore',
                anchor: '95%'
            }
```

And in other view a grid,and when I click some item of the grid,the combo select X value. But when I change the selection in the grid, the combo select correctly the new combo item of the grid selection,but visually the previous selection is still marked.

The store of the combo has 4 options:Sin Especificar,Provisional,Validad,Definitivo.

[image]

This is the code I use in my controller to select the value in the combo of the selected item in the gird:

```
Ext.getCmp('tfecomboEstados').setValue(record.data['id_estado_edicion']);
```

Any Idea why it's happening?
If I print the value and rawvalue,every time I select a new item on the grid,its correct,but visually the combo has selected the previous and actual values.

Comment: can you reproduce problem in sencha or js fiddle? fiddle will help a lot to troubleshoot your problem

Comment: I think the problem is on setValue, maybe setting the value you're not going to set the selected item

Comment: check the id s once this may cause when they have same ids

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Mr.George, I think the problem come when you set the value.

I can see here that in your combo you set the valueField as `value`.
And when you set the value programmatically, you did: `...setValue(record.data['id_estado_edicion']);`

Are you sure of the mapping between those two fields `id_estado_edicion` and `value`?

Maybe it's more :

```
Ext.getCmp('tfecomboEstados').setValue(record.get('value'));
```

Comment: In my case,id_estado_edicion is a number,and in the sencha documentation is says that the value passed must match with some valueField in the store. The selection is correct,the problem is visually ,the combo has the previous and actual item selected as shown in the picture abobe.